# Show that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0) $ but not differentiable at $(0,0) $.

Tags: calculus, continuity

Define $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ by $f(x,y)=(x+2y+y^2+|xy|,2x+y+x^2+|xy|)$ for $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$.Then show that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0) $ but not differentiable at 
$(0,0) $.

**My try:**

Consider the projection map $\pi_1(x,y)=x,\pi_2(x,y)=y$ Then $\pi_1\circ f=x+2y+y^2+|xy| ;\pi_2\circ f=2x+y+x^2+|xy|$ both the projection maps are continuous hence $f$ is continuous at $(0,0) $.

For differentiabilty:

Consider The Jacobian Matrix at $(0,0) $ ;$J_{|(0,0)}=$ \begin{bmatrix} u_x && u_y \\ v_x && v_y \end{bmatrix} where $u=x+2y+y^2+|xy|$ and $v=2x+y+x^2+|xy|$

on computing I got $J=$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 2 \\ 2 && 1 \end{bmatrix}.

Since $J$ does not vanish at $(0,0)$ so $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$

Where is the problem? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The alleged conclusion is wrong: $f(x,y) = f(0,0) + (x+2y, 2x+y) + \text {  the other stuff}.$ The map $(x,y) \to (x+2y, 2x+y)$ is linear, and the other stuff is $o(\sqrt {x^2+y^2}).$ Therefore $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0).$

Comment: How to read about continuity and differentiability of functions from $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$. Is Jacobian matrix not needed here? Is my approach wrong ?Which books to follow for this

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$ since both its component scalar fields are differentiable

Proof that $f_1$ is differentiable at (0, 0) $$ \lim_{{(h, k)} \to {(0 0)}} {{f_1(h, k) - f_1(0, 0) - h(f_1)_x(0, 0) - k(f_1)_y(0, 0)}\over {{(h^2 + k^2)}^{1/2}}} = \lim_{{(h, k)} \to {(0, 0)}}{{k^2 + |h||k|}\over {{(h^2+k^2)}^{1/2}}} = 0$$ similarly you can show that the other component scalar field is differentiable as well.